# Iterating through form controls in a nested formgroup in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a nested formgroup in Angular 5. Here is how it looks:

But while iterating through the form controls for the child formgroup, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Here is the nested formgroup object:
[image]
Here is the HTML file:

```
<div 
  *ngFor = "let parentControl of parentGroup.controls" 
  [formGroupName]="xyz">
  <custom-component 
    *ngFor="let childControl of parentControl.controls['conditions'].controls">
    Hello
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

Even I tried the following:

```
<div 
  *ngFor="let parentControl of parentGroup.controls 
  [formGroupName]="xyz">
  <custom-component 
    *ngFor="let childControl of parentControl.get('conditions').controls">
    Hello
  </custom-component>
</div>
```

So I want to loop through all the form controls inside the `formgroup` "conditions".

Could someone please let me know what I am missing out here?

Comment: parentGroup.controls is an object and not an array or iterable and ngFor only supports those. You either need to transform the object into an array. You could use something like `Object.keys(parentGroup.controls)` to get an array with the keys of your control and use those as list in the ngFor statement.

Comment: the first loop "parentGroup.controls" works fine for me. The error is occuring while I am trying to loop the controls for child formgroup which is "conditions". How do I use Object.keys in html?

Comment: That is because your root element is not a `FormGroup` but a `FormArray`. In the case of `FormArray`, `controls` is an array, hence ngFor works for that. But then in your `FormGroup`, `controls` is an object and your ngFor breaks.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to make this work? I want to loop through all the controls for "conditions" formgroup. Otherwise any inputs on what changes I need to have in this object to make it work?

Comment: Use Object. keys like I said in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks!! I have used it already but it says - Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Comment: Then maybe Object.keys is not available in the angular template expression syntax. It may not be the optimal solution, but you can create a function to map your object into an array. `toArray(obj){ return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]) }`. In the template you then do `*ngFor="let item of toArray(parentGroup.controls )"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added "objectKeys = Object.keys;" in the ts file and its working now. Appreciate your help!